# Helix 3d toolkit, get the position of a model

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I have a helix toolkit project, in WPF, visual studio 2015. Using the example [RectSelection](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/tree/develop/Source/Examples/WPF/ExampleBrowser/Examples/RectSelection) I have a 3d viewport in which I can select my objects, which are `BoxVisual3D.`
What I need to do, is return the 3d position of the selected object. I have:

```
  foreach (var model in models)
            {
                var geometryModel = model as GeometryModel3D;
                if (geometryModel != null)
                {
                    geometryModel.Material = geometryModel.BackMaterial = material;


                    //do stuff 
                    UserControl1.Point1Position = model.Transform; 

                    UserControl1.returnPoint.X = model.Transform.Value.M14;
                    UserControl1.returnPoint.Y = geometryModel.Transform.Value.M24;
                    UserControl1.returnPoint.Z = geometryModel.Transform.Value.M34;
                }
            }
```

But the values always return as 0. (I spawn the box myself, so i know they are not 0).
When I step through, there is a selected object, but the transform reads as all zeros. How can i get the position of a BoxVisual3D?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After nearly 3 years maybe not you but someone else could face with this issue. Here is my explanation.

If you created a Model3D with transform attribute you can use OffsetX, OffsetY, OffsetZ. But if you just created your BoxVisual3D with center attributes there will be no transform in it. Hence you just cant reach it. Create your objects with transform attribute. And another issue creating object in the specified Point3D. Here is my code:

```
my_point = new Point3D(-15,7,5);  
            var myTransform = new Transform3DGroup();
            
            TranslateTransform3D myTranslate = new TranslateTransform3D(my_point.X, my_point.Y, my_point.Z);


            myTransform.Children.Add(myTranslate);
            kontrol.Transform = myTransform; //ez
           
            myModel.Children.Add(kontrol);
```

And here is the getting the Transform back:

```
Transform3D mytransform = sourceobject.Transform;
                        Console.WriteLine(mytransform.Value.OffsetX + "," + mytransform.Value.OffsetY+"," + mytransform.Value.OffsetZ);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the Position of the Matrix3D you have to use the Offset Properties:

```
public static Point3D GetPosition(this Matrix3D m)
{
    return new Point3D
    {
        X = m.OffsetX,
        Y = m.OffsetY,
        Z = m.OffsetZ
    };
}
```